# Last value not showing up after slicing list

Tags: python, list, slice

```
Av = [32,5,3,1,3,4,5]
A = Av[0:int(len(Av)/2)]
B = Av[int(len(Av)/2):-1]
print(A,B)
```

When I run this block of code, I get

```
[32, 5, 3] [1, 3, 4]
```

The last value of Av is 5. But it is not showing up on the list B..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you have sliced the list till -1 which means the last element of the array and is excluded from the sliced array.

To get an array sliced till the end leave the end part of the slice code empty. Like this -

```
B = Av[int(len(Av)/2):]
```

Answer (score 2):

In python when you use index slicing `Av[a:b]` you get the elements from position `a` (included) to position `b` (excluded). Because -1 refers to the last position, if you do `Av[a:-1]`, the last element won't be included.

If you want to include the last element, just omit the final index -1, that is use `Av[a:]`. Your code should be like this:

```py
Av = [32,5,3,1,3,4,5]
A = Av[0:int(len(Av)/2)]
B = Av[int(len(Av)/2):]
print(A,B)
```

Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/7558835 answer. It explains very clearly how does index slicing work.

Answer (score 2):

When you use the slice `[x:-1]`, it doesn't include the value at index `-1` (last position), because it is non-inclusive.

Instead, use `[x:]`, which will give a slice that includes `x` and all values to its right:

```
B = Av[int(len(Av)/2):]
```

Output:

```
>>>B
>>>[1, 3, 4, 5]
```